# Upgraded from Wheezy to Buster and now having power problems

Tags: power-supply, raspbian-buster

I was using a Raspberry Pi 2 B several years ago when Wheezy was the latest version. When I did a clean install of Buster just now and tried to use the Raspberry Pi with some peripherals in my application, the battery I was using did not provide enough power anymore.

When all the peripherals are plugged in and I connect the Raspberry Pi to my battery through the USB power port, the Raspberry Pi just continually resets just past the splash screen with all the colors and doesn't ever get to the desktop. The same thing happens when I use my laptop USB port to power the Raspberry Pi.

I have a Wi-Fi dongle and an Arduino hooked up to the Raspberry Pi and getting power from it. Everything worked with Wheezy. Now with Buster I have to either unplug the Wi-Fi dongle and Arduino or use a more powerful power source than my battery (a 2A wall wart works). I'd like to be able to use what I used to use with Wheezy.

UPDATE 1: My Wi-Fi dongle and Arduino were connected through a USB hub. If I disconnect the hub and insert the dongle and Arduino directly into the USB ports on the Raspberry Pi, it all works. Perhaps there is some sort of problem with using the hub. Though if I use the 2A wall wort instead of my battery, I can still use the hub even with Buster.

It seems odd that changing the operating system version would change the power requirements, but that seems to be what is happening. Is there some way to get around this problem?

UPDATE 2: The USB port drivers appear to have changed from what those in Wheezy. That seems to be causing the issue. But I can't find anyone else that has had this issue so I guess it's an unusual problem. I guess the only solution is to add another battery to power my USB hub, which is unfortunate since I am using this on a model car and don't have the space or weight for it.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with OS. If you really have PSU problems it is more likely a PSU failure. 6 year old capacitors fail - particularly if they haven't been used. We have no idea what "hook the Raspberry Pi up to my battery" means! (If you have a 6 year old battery it is almost certainly dead.)

Comment: Incidentally I hope you didn't try to "Upgraded from Wheezy to Buster" even an experienced user would be challenged by this. If you did a fresh install you should remove the misleading data from your Question.

Comment: Milliways, to respond to your points I clarified in my question that I did a clean install of Buster and that I use a battery to power the Raspberry Pi. The battery worked fine with Wheezy but would not power the Raspberry Pi after I installed Buster. It may have something to do with going through the USB hub. After I took the hub out and plugged the peripherals directly into the Raspberry Pi, the battery worked fine.

Comment: It seems unlike that the OS is using more power..  More like your under voltage is caused by too much draw by connected devices.  Or your power supply has changed or not producing as much current.